# How to mock multiple values from a mocked module?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I am trying to mock the module 'jwt-decode' and I can successfully mock one return value using the following:

```
 jest.mock('jwt-decode', () => () => ({ data: { userRole: 2, checklist: mockUser.account.checklist }}))
```

This works for one test that needs the decoded jwt to yield a userRole of 2. However, my next test needs the userRole to be one and this is where the issue arises.

Is there a proper way to return the userRole as 2 for the first instance of the test and 1 for the next instance of the test?

Answer (score 1):

You can change mock implementation of your mocked function per test by calling `mockImplementation` or `mockImplementationOnce` on your mocked function with new implementation as a parameter, here is the details: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mock-implementations

In your case it would be something like that:

```
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';

jest.mock('jwt-decode', () => jest.fn(() => ({
    data: { userRole: 2, checklist: mockUser.account.checklist },
})));

it('should test behavior with userRole equal to 2', () => {
    // your test here 
});

it('here we update mock implementation and test behavior with userRole equal to 1', () => {
    jwt_decode.mockImplementationOnce(() => ({
        data: { userRole: 1, checklist: mockUser.account.checklist },
    }));
    // your test here
});

it('since we used mockImplementationOnce method in the test above, here we again will be using initial mock implementation - userRole equal to 2', () => {
    // your test here
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks for responding, however, this throws the error that jwt_decode.mockImplementationOnce is not a function.

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad, I did not wrap exported function in `jest.fn`. `jest.mock` just mock module itself but we also need to mock function which is exported from the module in order to have opportunity to override it implementation per test. I've updated the answer, now should work. Give me know if not

Comment: Hello, I am trying to achieve something similar and receive the `jwt_decode.mockImplementationOnce` error, even with your updated answer.

Comment: The same error as mentioned above `jwt_decode.mockImplementationOnce is not a function`. I was able to solve this by mocking it differently.

Comment: @Samantha could you send a link to some sandbox with reproducing of the issue, or at least to github with the code.